# Mystery Margin/Padding Appearing Intermittently

Tags: javascript, jquery

We're almost ready to take this site live but there is something odd going on that I'd love some help with.

http://sbt.publishpath.com/

If you visit that site, you'll notice that the links to the left of the phone automatically cycle or you can hover over them to update. But if you quickly move the mouse over more than one link and then immediately move your mouse out of that area with the links, it adds spacing to the dark area beneath. The extra spacing disappears once the autocycle code kicks in.

I'm stumped, any ideas?

Comment: I noticed only that when pointer passes over "3 options", the black area appears

Comment: Yes, I thought I'd narrowed it down to the number of times, but I went over just 1 and off, 1 and off a bunch of times in a row and it happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
#content-phone
{
  height: 432px;
}
```

and get rid of the min-height style.

When you switch from showing `#textMessages` to `#defaultMessage`, the `#textMessages` div has a slight delay after the `#defaultMessage` box is shown, so both are briefly visible. This causes the `#content-phone` div to expand downward pushing the footer content farther down the page.

It's probably a mistake in how you're hiding the `#textMessages` div after hovering out of the list, but explicitly setting the height should fix it.